# AngularJS Link multi JSON with unique ID

Tags: json, angularjs, mongodb

I have 2 collections in mongoDB:

message:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("542e65368a1cec1227ae2bac"),
        "message" : "hello"
 }
```

categories:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("542e65368a1cec1227ae2bac"),
        "result" : {
                "full" : "voyage",
                "others" : "voyage"
        }
}
```

I can display the ID from the collection **message**:

```
 "542e65368a1cec1227ae2bac, hello":
```

With:

{{image._id}}, {{image.message}}

From my JSON:

```
{ "images" : 
   [ 
      { 
       "_id" : "542e65368a1cec1227ae2bac",
       "message" : "hello"
      } 
   ] 
}
```

But I would like to display also **"voyage"**.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('fCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.messages = {
    "images": [{
      "_id": "542e65368a1cec1227ae2bac",
      "message": "hello"
    }]
  }

  $scope.categories = [{
    "_id": "542e65368a1cec1227ae2bac",
    "result": {
      "full": "voyage",
      "others": "voyage"
    }
  }]


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="fCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="message in messages.images">
      <p>{{message._id}} - {{message.message}}
        <p ng-repeat="cat in categories | filter: {'_id':message._id}">{{cat.result.others}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! So if I understand I just need to do a filter? filter: {'_id':message._id} ?